# Undefined: function 'ab' with a return value is being called inside a function 'cd' which does not return but only calls 'ab'

Tags: javascript, function

An example I tried in dev tools:

```
var ab = function() {
  return 2
}

ab(); //2

var cd = function() {
  ab()
}

cd(); //undefined
```

I would like to think that `cd()` call will also shows 2, but it show undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the result of `ab()`, otherwise the [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Description) returns the default value `undefined`.

> By default, functions return `undefined`. To return any other value, the function must have a return statement that specifies the value to return.

```
var cd = function() {
        return ab();
    };
```

```js
var ab = function () {
        return 2;
    };

console.log(ab()); // 2

var cd = function () {
        return ab();
    };

console.log(cd()); // 2
```

Comment: or use `console.log(2)` instead of `return 2`

Comment: @robertotomás, that does not help to return something else.

Comment: very good! but he didn't say "return", he said "show". I'm not saying that you are wrong, just noting that there's more than one way to answer the question for the guy :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a `return` statement:

```js
var ab = function() {
  return 2
}

console.log(ab()) // => 2

var cd = function() {
  return ab()
}

console.log(cd()) // => 2
```